# Chaining in Javascript

Tags: javascript

could you please explain me this piece of code? Thank you.

```
items.addItem("a").addItem("b").addItem("c").run();
```

Comment: What framework/library are you using here?

Comment: not sure if this should be tagged with closures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an example of a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what framework you're using, but the addItem method returns the parent instance (`return this`), so you can call another method upon the output.